# Embedded videos started giving "An error occurred." message

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

i've been running sites w/ functional video embeds for awhile, & have just recently started seeing widespread "An error occurred." messages, which is seemingly pervasive

[An error occurred. Try watching this video on www.youtube.com, or enable JavaScript if it is disabled in your browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isLng.png)

i've tried embedding on different sites/pages, looked at available forums on the subject, refreshed cache settings, ensured javascript is enabled, viewed from multiple browsers...

it began occurring around Nov-Dec 2023 [Happy New Year! ]

i typically cycle videos almost daily, & pull them directly from YouTube's embed function

Comment: Can you provide an example URL of public webpage having this issue?

Comment: hey, sure can https://www.virtualrecordstore.com/music-video-section.html

Comment: hello, still seeking a resolution to this issue -- it's been ongoing for months now -- embedding videos directly from YouTube using HTML is producing an error on seemingly all pages [using Hostgator/C-Panel/File Manager] -- curious if this is an OS issue [Safari displaying Javascript, altho i tried Chrome as well...] or rooted elsewhere

Comment: updating: issue ongoing; shows Error on Windows & Mac; multiple browsers

Comment: updating again: embedded video via Shopify [tested on a page] rather than Hostgator [C-Panel -> File Manager] & it worked(!)

so i copied that exact HTML code from Shopify page & pasted it into Hostgator HTML & got: same result [An Error Occurred...] ‍♂️

my next step is to talk w/ Hostgator; so i'll do that & keep ya posted...